# Does auth.log store mysql log in attempts?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

Im seeing a few root login entries in the auth.log in one of our database servers but I dont know if these are applications logging in to our database, or ssh log ins.

FWIW We are rotating our database users to stop using root.

Comment: Wonder why the downvote... This is something I couldn't find in the documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, mysql is having it's own logs for logging.

Comment: Thats what I thought... so if I see 3 logins at the exact same second I should be concerned... Thanks!

Comment: Well... obviously somebody is trying to login for root via e.g. ssh. I assume, you have logon for root turned off as well as added some things like fail2ban on your box.

Comment: Yeah but I still needed to make sure about this, I thought since one of the apps connecting to this box does it via certificates for remote management that it would use OpenSSH and that it would trigger the auth.log entries